# Can't open clojure the project in Intellij IDEA with La Clojure

Tags: clojure, intellij-idea, la-clojure

I was going through this tutorial 
http://wiki.jetbrains.net/intellij/Getting_started_with_La_Clojure and I got stuck here 
http://wiki.jetbrains.net/intellij/Getting_started_with_La_Clojure#Opening_project_in_IntelliJ_IDEA. I don't know way but 'open project' dialog does show the file 'project.clj'. So I'm not able open the clojure project. (And also I don't know how to create new one)
Is this bug of IDEA/La clojure or I did something wrong?

Comment: You may want to check out [Cursive](http://cursiveclojure.com/) instead.

Comment: Highlight project.clj and press 'Ok'.

Comment: Chiron, there is no 'project.clj'. It does not show me this file

Comment: Jeremy Heiler, thank you for link. It looks nice!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To open/import clj projects, you need to have the Leiningen plugin installed.

Unfortunately, the latest official release of the lein plugin for intellij doesn't work well with Intellij13 (crashed my idea on load every time until removed manually).
I'm guessing that because of Cursive there wasn't a newer release even though the latest version of the plugin on github does work.
I followed the instructions on the lein plugin's git page to create a plugin bundle from the latest version: https://github.com/derkork/intellij-leiningen-plugin

Assuming you're using Intellij13, creating the bundle yourself and then installing it from disk will enable you to open clj project files.